# ReferenceError: algoliasearch is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, algolia, instantsearch.js

I'm trying to build and Algolia system with instantsearch.js from algolia but when I run this code I get an error of "ReferenceError: algoliasearch is not defined". Is it because I'm missing some imports?
How do I fix this?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="sytlesheet" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.css@7.3.1/themes/reset-min.css" integrity="sha256-t2ATOGCtAIZNnzER679jwcFcKYfLlw01gli6F6oszk8=" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="input-container">
                <input id="search-input" placeholder="Search for Products">
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div id="hits">

            </div>
            <div id="pagination">

            </div>
        </main>

    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

app.js

```
const searchClient =  algoliasearch('', '');

const search = instantsearch({
    indexName: "users",
    searchClient,
    urlSync: true,
})

search.addWidgets([
    instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
        container: "#search-input",
    }),

    instantsearch.widgets.hits({
        container: "#hits",
        hitsPerPage: 10,
        templates: {
            item: document.getElementById("hit-template").innerHTML,
            empty: "We didn't find any results for the search <em>\"{{query}}\"<em>"
        }
    }),
    
    instantsearch.widgets.pagination({
        container: "#pagination",
    }),
]);


search.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cdn script register is umd module which registers `instantsearch` object in window instead of `algoliasearch`

Comment: How do I fix this then?

Comment: It seems you're missing this script to load `algoliasearch` https://cdnjs.com/libraries/algoliasearch

Comment: After adding this line to my index.html "<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/algoliasearch/4.3.1/algoliasearch-lite.umd.js"></script>" I get this error Uncaught Error: 
Usage: instantsearch({
  appId: 'my_application_id',
  apiKey: 'my_search_api_key',
  indexName: 'my_index_name'
});
    at new t (InstantSearch.js:80)
    at t (to-factory.js:10)
    at app.js:5

Comment: You might have to check version between 2 scripts above on your own to make it work together (avoid version collision though)

Comment: I just have had a quick look on the document. It seems to have no property called `searchClient` at the init step https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/getting-started.html#initialization